identify cipher?
I have this, I just need help identifying the cipher. Any tips/pointers are welcome!

Text version (for those who can't view images)
TREASURE MAP LEGEND

X O H K D M G H D Q A F
B L Q G S S O J D C D A
R B M G F H C Q W L W K
H A U N P K U X S S J Q
T M K I J Z L R Z J O R
P V K Q A G Z Q Y N H S
R X U R I B E Y V F V X
C D V X M J J P Q Q W V
K V Z S Y B D G J V E V
T V T E B H L Y E B D Q
X T N Z F S Q R F B Y H
V S A M M U M P R B E J
G F L O W R O E P V O J
D Q E O Q M I R A X F G
I X Y S T I B W N Z D K
Y Y S Q L S G S O A P X
-----------------------------
A K T T R W H O S S L N M R D
-----------------------------


Please help me understand what attributes I need to display, I'd be more than happy to add however that's as much information I have. I didn't think I needed much since  I'm not asking for help with the puzzle or claiming to have made the puzzle, - I just need help identifying the puzzle.

Just need a link to where you got it from and that would be fine, we just ask for that to make sure there's no plagiarism and nothing from any competitions etc :)
